# Creating css scroll bar while already have div for text

Tags: html, css

I'm learning css and want to use it more. So far I'm using table but found out css is more flexible.
My current problem is creating a vertical scroll bar while I already have div tags surrounding my texts. What I did below wasn't working properly:

I'm using ColdFusion 10 to loop over a query results and I'm using css to style the texts:

This is part of my css:

```
  <style>
    #Meeting{
       font: 0.7em  Book Antiqua, Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
       font-size: 12px;
       color: #4f4f4f;
       position: absolute;
       top: 495px;
       left:308px;
    }

    #scroll {
     background-color: #00FFFF;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     overflow: scroll;
   }        
  </style>

  <div id="Meeting">
    <cfoutput query="GetNextMeeting">
    #MeetingDay#, #MeetingMonth#/#MeetingDate#/#MeetingYear#<br>
    </cfoutput>
  </div>
```

Since the output query sometimes can be longer than the space it can hold, I thought I want to add a vertical scroll bar.
I did the following and it is not working. The scroll bar and the text don't seem to work together.

```
  <div id="scroll">
   <div id="Meeting">
    <cfoutput query="GetNextMeeting">
    #MeetingDay#, #MeetingMonth#/#MeetingDate#/#MeetingYear#<br>
    </cfoutput>
   </div>
  </div
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as 'ColdFusion'?

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it by combining the two css:

```
#scroll {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   width: 300px;
   height: 150px;
   overflow: scroll;
   font: 0.7em  Book Antiqua, Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
   font-size: 11px;
   color: #4f4f4f;
}
```